# Icecast Stream Keeps Repeating

Tags: audio, streaming, icecast

I have successfully done a test audio stream to the free, "Icecast," server. However, when I stop my audio source, after some seconds, eg, ten, then once that audio stream has finished, after about six seconds the audio stream repeats playing, then does so after the same time interval, again for many times. Each time the volume of these repetitions, decreases, I am using the, "BUTT," encoder, version, 0.1.16. I have muted my mic and tried muting my speakers, however that has not solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Icecast server has a buffer it flushes to clients upon connect.  That way, the client buffers can fill rapidly for a quick start to playback.

What's happening here is that nothing is being added to the buffer, so clients connect, get the contents of that buffer, and then the stream ends.  The client must be re-connecting repeatedly, and it keeps getting that same buffer.

You probably need to adjust the `<source-timeout>` in your [Icecast config file](https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html).  That way, when your source disconnects, the mountpoint will be dropped after a shorter period of time.

Comment: Hello Brad, Many thanks for your prompt reply with guidance and suggestion. I altered the values in, "<source-timeout>," several times, however there is no change. There is still the repeating effect. Perhaps you would clarify the following. Is it alright to leave, "<hostname>locahost</hostname>," as is it is? Also, to leave the, "bind-address," as the default? Best regards.

Comment: @Daylight The problem would then be on the client.  Your `hostname` should be set to whatever your hostname is... if you're not using `localhost`, then you should change it to whatever you're using.  As for `bind-address`, it should be set to whatever network address you want your server to listen on.  You can use `0.0.0.0` to listen on all network addresses.

Comment: Brad, Thanks again for your reply. I'm running, "Icecast," Version - win32_2.4.4 - on Windows XP SP 3. Perhaps this version of, "Icecast," is not compatible with my OS! I have my other PC, Windows 10, so perhaps if I installed, "Icecast," on 10, then if it is a compatibility issue with XP then this might be what's needed. Regards, Daylight.

Comment: Brad, I was wondering if the server access port might be causing this repeating issue!